# n choose k in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

```
    .text
        addi    $v0, $zero, 5
        syscall
        add $a0, $v0, $zero  
    
        addi    $v0, $zero, 5
        syscall
        add $a1, $v0, $zero  #call choose function
        jal choose

        add $a0, $v0, $zero  #print result
        addi    $v0, $zero, 1
        syscall

        addi    $v0, $zero, 10   #exit program
        syscall

choose:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -16    
        sw  $ra, 0($sp)        # save the return address on the stack
        sw  $s0, 4($sp)        # save s0 on the stack
        sw  $a0, 8($sp)        # save n on the stack
        sw  $a1, 12($sp)       # save k on the stack

        slt     $t0, $a0, $a1     # check if n < k
        beq     $t0, $1, choose_end
        beq     $a0, $0, choose_one   # check if n == 0 or k == 0
        beq     $a1, $0, choose_one

        addi    $a0, $a0, -1     # calculate choose(n-1, k-1)
        addi    $a1, $a1, -1
        jal     choose
        move    $s0, $v0

        addi    $a0, $a0, 1     # calculate choose(n-1, k)
        jal     choose
        add     $v0, $s0, $v0     # add val1 and val2

        j   choose_end

choose_one:
        li  $v0, 1             # return 1
        j   choose_end

choose_end:
        lw  $ra, 0($sp)        # restore the return address
        lw  $s0, 4($sp)        # restore s0
        addi    $sp, $sp, 16     # deallocate space from stack
        jr  $ra                # return to caller
```

Idk what's wrong with this code

I enter 2 and 3 and the result is 4

Comment: Step through it with a debugger to find where things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

- `beq $t0, $1, choose_end` is not comparing `$t0` to a constant value `1`. This instruction is comparing `$t0` with register No.1, which is a register `$at`, which is reserved for an assembler. You should use `bne $t0, $0, choose_end` instead to check the comparision result.
- You saved `n` and `k` to the stack, but never restored them. Some code to restore them should be added after the first recursive function call.
- You forgot to set the return value, which should be `0`, for the `n < k` case.

Fixed code:

```
choose:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -16
        sw  $ra, 0($sp)        # save the return address on the stack
        sw  $s0, 4($sp)        # save s0 on the stack
        sw  $a0, 8($sp)        # save n on the stack
        sw  $a1, 12($sp)       # save k on the stack

        slt     $t0, $a0, $a1     # check if n < k
        # use proper comparision, and go to setting the return value
        #beq     $t0, $1, choose_end
        bne     $t0, $0, choose_zero
        beq     $a0, $0, choose_one   # check if n == 0 or k == 0
        beq     $a1, $0, choose_one

        addi    $a0, $a0, -1     # calculate choose(n-1, k-1)
        addi    $a1, $a1, -1
        jal     choose
        move    $s0, $v0

        # restore n and k
        lw $a0, 8($sp)
        lw $a1, 12($sp)
        # n-1, not n+1, should be used for the next call
        #addi    $a0, $a0, 1     # calculate choose(n-1, k)
        addi    $a0, $a0, -1     # calculate choose(n-1, k)
        jal     choose
        add     $v0, $s0, $v0     # add val1 and val2

        j   choose_end

choose_one:
        li  $v0, 1             # return 1
        j   choose_end

        # set the return value for n < k case
choose_zero:
        li $v0, 0

choose_end:
        lw  $ra, 0($sp)        # restore the return address
        lw  $s0, 4($sp)        # restore s0
        addi    $sp, $sp, 16     # deallocate space from stack
        jr  $ra                # return to caller
```

Comment: The "symbolic" name for `$0` is `$zero`; if the OP is confused between immediates vs. register numbers / names, a symbolic name might be even clearer.  A `bne $t0, 0, choose_end` pseudo-instruction with an immediate zero would actually work (but less efficiently than using the zero register).  You did explain the fact that `$1` is `$at` sufficiently, though, so really it's a matter of style; I prefer `$zero` in code using other register names.

Comment: To clarify, in MIPS you cannot use `bne`, `beq`, etc. to compare a register to a constant. You can only compare registers to registers. (Technically you can compare a register to a constant zero, but that's only because the `$zero` register exists, which always holds a value of zero.)